# Ubercart/Securepages site breaks overnight!? Can't POST (login/add to cart)

Tags: 7, ubercart, users, http-request

This site seemingly broke overnight without any changes being made to the configuration.. this is a production site:

https://www.skinnyboyswagclub.com/cardigan

Add an item to your cart and watch the network activity.. It redirects through a 302. Is this secure pages switching to https? (even though it's submitting from https?)

Nothing gets added, no errors.

Can't login either. Logging in with the correct password (guest/guestpass) doesn't work either.

I did add another dns record the other day to point ".dev." at another server. Could that have broken the production site at www.?

I removed the record just now, in case..

Since this is an issue on a production site and I can't even log in, I'm BEGGING for help! :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. You can look at [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37712/ubercart-items-wont-add-to-cart-unless-cache-is-cleared) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35772/cant-add-items-to-cart) to get a bit more insight as to what my problem ended up being. Here are somethings you may want to try;

- Enable your cookies via your settings.php file. (This is something that helps with securepages).
- Enable secure pages across all your pages. This will test if its the issue with securepages losing its session values. If it works, then you need to wait till secure pages gets fixed OR just make every page on your site HTTPS.
- Turn caching off. For some reason, this was conflicting with my current setup. It wasn't until I did this that ALL my problems went away.

Good luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I had inadvertently uploaded the settings.php from the dev. website to the www. site, so the cookie domain was wrong. I'm going through many of my questions and finally picking answers, sorry for the delay!